# Get the ID of the object from the selection list. Django, forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to get the ID of my object from the drop down list, how can I do it? is it possible directly? not to use the query set to search for it from the 'cleanded data' method?

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    type_product = models.ForeignKey(Type)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Time
        fields = ('type_product'
                  )
```

**views.py**

```
data = product_form.cleaned_data['type_product']
# ^ but it does not return id, how to get 'id' object 'Type' from selected option
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: product_form.cleaned_data['type_product'].id

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
 data = product_form.cleaned_data['type_product'].id
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` will be the `Type` model object so something like this should work:

```
data = product_form.cleaned_data['type_product']
print(data.id)
```